# Cypher match path with intermediate nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

I have the following graph with `Stop` (red) and `Connection` (green) nodes.

[image]

I want to find the shortest path from `A` to `C` using a cost property on `Connection`.

I would like to avoid making `Connection` a relationship because than I loose the `CONTAINS` relationship of `Foo`.

I can match a single hop like this

```
MATCH p=(:Stop {name:'A'})<-[:BEGINS_AT]-(:Connection)-[:ENDS_AT]->(:Stop {name:'B'}) RETURN p
```

but this does not work with an arbitrary number of `Connection`s like it would with relationships and `[*]`.

I also tried to make a projection down to simple relationships but it seems like I cannot do something with this without GDS.

```
MATCH (s1:Stop)<-[:BEGINS_AT]-(c:Connection)-[:ENDS_AT]->(s2:Stop) RETURN id(s1) AS source, id(s2) AS target, c.cost AS cost
```

Note that the connection is unidirectional, so it must not be possible to go from `C` to `A`.

Is there a way to do this without any Neo4j plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get all usable paths (without plugins):

```
WITH ['BEGINS_AT', 'ENDS_AT'] AS types
MATCH p=(a:Stop)-[:BEGINS_AT|ENDS_AT*]-(b:Stop)
WHERE a.name = 'A' AND b.name = 'B' AND
  ALL(i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(p)-1) WHERE TYPE(RELATIONSHIPS(p)[i]) = types[i%2])
RETURN p
```

To get the shortest path:

```
WITH ['BEGINS_AT', 'ENDS_AT'] AS types
MATCH p=(a:Stop)-[:BEGINS_AT|ENDS_AT*]-(b:Stop)
WHERE a.name = 'A' AND b.name = 'B' AND
  ALL(i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(p)-1) WHERE TYPE(RELATIONSHIPS(p)[i]) = types[i%2])
RETURN p
ORDER BY LENGTH(p)
LIMIT 1;
```

or

```
WITH ['BEGINS_AT', 'ENDS_AT'] AS types
MATCH p=shortestpath((a:Stop)-[:BEGINS_AT|ENDS_AT*]-(b:Stop))
WHERE a.name = 'A' AND b.name = 'B' AND
  ALL(i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(p)-1) WHERE TYPE(RELATIONSHIPS(p)[i]) = types[i%2])
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thanks! The trick with ensuring the right direction by looking at the even/uneven relationship types is really neat. I added a cost optimization like this `REDUCE(total = 0, n IN NODES(p) | total + COALESCE(n.cost, 0)) AS totalCost`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the weighted shortest path, then it is the easiest to use GDS or even APOC plugin. You could probably create a shortest weighted path function with cypher but it would be not optimized. I can only think of finding all paths between the two nodes and suming the weights. In the next step you would filter the path with the minimum sum of weight. This would not scale well though.

As for the second part of your question I would need more information as I dont know exactly what you want.